# Swift mapkit how to hide user's location pin

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I could not find any documentation on that so maybe it is not possible I am asking anyway. I need to show the blue dot for user location. My mapview is filled with pins and sometimes my user are clicking on the blue circle of the user location which opens a small user picture pin. How can I remove that? It's annoying if something is behind.

[image: user location pin]

So far, I got to identify when I open the annotationview like that :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if(view.annotation?.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) != true){
        print("test");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to cancel it from showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 99% of the solution - You have identified when the user location annotation is selected.  All you need to do to complete your task is deselect it;

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: false)
        return
    }

    // Handle selection of other annotations if required...
}
```

Comment: ahh i was close, i did return directly but i did not think of deselectannotation. thanks